# Separando usando o sinal de + ao ler dados do usuário

Tags: python

Desculpem-me pela pergunta básica. É que eu não entendo quando temos que usar o `+` no `Input`. Segue o exemplo de um comando abaixo. Por quê meu código não funciona quando coloco o `str(i)` entre vírgulas??

```
i = 1
textos = []
texto = input("Digite o texto " + str(i) +" (aperte enter para sair):")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu código não funciona com as vírgulas porque, ao por vírgulas, você está criando implicitamente uma tupla (uma estrutura de dados). No seu caso, a função `input` recebe uma string por parâmetro, não uma tupla. Por via das dúvidas use sempre o sinal `+` para concatenação, ou, uma função chamada `format`. Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
mensagem = 'Digite o texto {} (aperte enter para sair):'.format(i)
texto = input(mensagem)
```

onde o `{}` será substituído pelo valor passado por parâmetro no método `format` (nesse caso a variável `i`).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [operador de formatação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) `%`, por exemplo:

```
i = 1
textos = []
texto = input("Digite o texto %d (aperte enter para sair):" % (i) )
```

Ou então você pode usar o [método `format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format), por exemplo:

```
i = 1
textos = []
texto = input("Digite o texto {} (aperte enter para sair):".format(i))
```

Comment: Interessante Lacobus - No caso o (i) seria uma variável qualquer? Por exemplo: texto = input("Digite o texto %d (aperte enter para sair):" % (5) ) seria Digite o texto 5 ??